# VirtualBox issuing error message "Kernel driver is not installed"

Tags: software-installation, 20.04, kernel, virtualbox

I am new to Ubuntu and VirtualBox is issuing the error message "kernel driver is not installed". I can't even remove it from my device. Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yVBO.png) with the error message with more details of the error I am receiving. Can someone help me please?

Comment: Youssef, have you already tried to follow the instructions provided by the error message you've uploaded? Could you share the results of it with us?

Comment: Have you installed VirtualBox from the default ubuntu apt repositories or from oracle apt repositories?

Comment: I installed it from the oracel webside, i didnt follow the error because I dintnt understand what is not working.

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving error messages when you run `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig`, then you will need to compile some kernel drivers. Fortunately, it’s not too difficult.

1. Open a terminal
2. Install some basics:
   `sudo apt install build-essential module-assistant`
3. Then: 
   `sudo m-a prepare`
4. Finally:
   `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig`

This should do what you’re looking for.